# What are the Pros and Cons to feeding my Corn Snake filtered/bottled water rather than tap water?

Tags: snakes

I was just told today to NEVER feed my Corn snake tap water. But I can't really afford to supply bottled/filtered water for him and it's slightly inconvenient. I know that it can cause a build up of bacteria in a young corn snakes intestine, possibly leading to digestive problems later in life and a pre-mature death, but how likely is that? If the fluoride, chlorine and chemicals are not concentrated enough that it doesn't make human's drop dead, then how bad can it be?

Comment: Humans are slightly more massive than a snake.  Snakes might also be more sensitive.